# How to pass array of struct(User defined data type) as an input to call procedure in mule

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-el

In my project we have a requirement where we have to insert an array of struct as an input parameter.How i can achieve that.
I don't want to use the approach suggested here 
https://dzone.com/articles/passing-java-arrays-in-oracle-stored-procedure-fro

I want to use the inbuilt objects given in mule.

Answer (score 0):

> we have to insert an array of struct as an input parameter

Where you want to insert this array ?

> array of struct

can we consider the User defined data type as POJOs ( just java object?) ?

> I want to use the inbuilt objects given in mule.

As I can see in the link, the example use Java + Mule component. Should I guess that you want to avoid Java code?

Please, elaborate your use case... hard to replicate

Comment: I want to insert this array of struct in as an input to procedure call.